# Why is HandlerThread not getting GCed?

Tags: android, android-handler

I have a scenario where i create and destroy objects of a class which contains a static inner class inherited by HandlerThread. When the object is created, the thread and looper starts and when the object is destroyed, it quits the thread and waits for it to complete.

My problem is that, even though the m_myThread.getLooper() returns null and the Thread is at state TERMINATED, my myThread object does not get garbage collected.

```
class myThread extends HandlerThread{
...
}
```

Thanks for any insight...

Edit: here is the code
I have two buttons. One calls startThread() and the other calls stopThread(). After this is done a few times I can see that the file-descriptor count has been increased. But this doesn't happen if I comment mDialog.show();

```
private void startThread(){

    mDialog = new Dialog(mContext);

    mHandlerThread = new HandlerThread("mythread");
    mHandlerThread.start();
    mHandler = new Handler(mHandlerThread.getLooper(), MainActivity.this);

    mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(1);
    mHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(2, 1000);

}

private void stopThread(){
    mHandlerThread.quit();
    try {
        mHandlerThread.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mHandlerThread = null;

    mDialog = null;             
}

@Override
public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(msg.what){
    case 1:
        mDialog.setTitle("alert dialog test");
        mDialog.show();
        break;
    case 2:
        mDialog.dismiss();
        break;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: any reason for extending HandlerThread?

Comment: well thats the best way to use the handlerthread isn't it?

Comment: not exactly, create a new HandlerThread then start() it and create a Handler with Looper parameter set to ht.get looper()

Comment: ok. tried your method. but my issue is still there. Actually what happens is, if i .show() a dialog from a handlerthread, that thrread does not get cleaned by GC even if it is terminated and nulled.

Comment: did you quit() your HandlerThread? or quitSafely()?

Comment: BTW do you really need a HandlerThread?  simple Handler is not enough?

Comment: sorry @pskink, i quit the thread and even do a .join() and wait for it to complete, but it still didn't work. and yes I need a separate thread for it, cant use a simple handler.